# On the Symmetrized Product $AB+BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I have encountered the matrix $P=P^T$,
\begin{align*}
P:=AB+BA,
\end{align*}
where $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and (in my case) $A=A^T$, $B=B^T$ and $1 \succeq A,B\succeq 0$.

The matrix $P$ is referred to as *symmetrized product* in *Lax, Linear Algebra and its Applications* and presented in the context of Linear Matrix Inequalities.

I have found little information on this kind of matrices and wanted to ask if anybody has additional references on these matrices? It would also be interesting to know in which context these matrices are encountered. The matrix $P$ seems to be quite special and it might be called differently in other literature.

Comment: Search for "Jordan Algebra".